# Microsoft Virtual Wifi Miniport - Unexplained

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have just reinstalled my OS with Windows 7 X64 Ultimate and for some reason I have 2 "Microsoft Virtual Wifi Miniport" adapters installed.
I can't for the the life of me think what app did this!
When I uninstall via device manager and reboot they get reinstalled again!

Does anybody know how I can see which app on my PC is installing these adapters?

Answer (score 1):

Windows installed it. Wireless Hosted Network, you can create virtual access point with that adapter. To disable `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork` then `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow`. Actually you can't uninstall because it part of os